# Changing a read only: /proc/sys/vm/max_map_count

Tags: process

I am trying to change my /proc/sys/vm/max_map_count file in order to increase the number of processes.
Is there a workaround to edit this read only file?

Answer (score 0):

It's a dirty hack.
Instead, you can add a row:

```
vm.max_map_count=...your_count...
```

to the /etc/sysctl.conf